# CSV .count in Python 3?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I'm switching over my python script into python 3 and I'm having trouble porting a portion of my csv evaluation code.

In python 2.7.5, this segment of code worked just fine:

```
filename=askopenfilename()

with open(filename, 'rb') as Order:
    reader = csv.reader(Order, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    OrderList = []
    first = Order.next()
    if (first.count("Web ID") == 1):
        OrderList.append("Digi-key")
        OrderList.append(first)
```

Now I've since changed the `Order.next()` line to next(Order) so it'll work w/ python 3, although I can't seem to find the python 3 equivalent of `if (first.count("Web ID") == 1):`

I've looked through the CSV module documentation for Python 3 and I may have missed something and I am not doing the greatest trying to figure it out.

The portion I'm trying to evaulate is this (changed numbers to maintain privacy):

```
Web ID,Access ID,Salesorder Number,Shipping Method,Payment Method,
49488634,84901,37873472,U.S. Postal Service Priority Mail* (2-3 Day Delivery to most US addresses)(order by 8:00 PM CT),Foo,

Shipping Address
...
```

The current error is this:

```
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post, or make up, a portion of the CSV file? Just the first few lines.

Comment: What exactly happens when you run the code with Python 3?

Comment: In python 2, you open csv files as `open(csvfile, 'rb')`, in 3 you do `open(csvfile, newline='')`.  This may (or may not) be your exact problem here, but it can definitely lead to hard-to-track-down bugs down the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `count` is implemented by strings or lists. In your case, you are calling it on a string, which you retrieve from the file object by calling its `next` method. On Python 3, when you open a file in binary mode, you get an iterable of bytestrings, not strings. Type `bytes` also implements `count`, but you can only count occurrences of bytestrings in a bytestring, otherwise you get a `TypeError`:

```
In [1]: b'hello'.count(b'el')
Out[1]: 1

In [2]: b'hello'.count('el')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-df699ac18654> in <module>()
----> 1 b'hello'.count('el')

TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

You are probably going to have to open the file in text mode for CSV parsing anyway, because
the [`csv.reader` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) says:

> `csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`
>
> Return a reader
>   object which will iterate over lines in the given csvfile. csvfile can
>   be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a
>   **string** each time its `__next__()` method is called — file objects and
>   list objects are both suitable.

Note the emphasis on the word "string" that I added.  You should open the file in text mode, and preferably, with `newline=''`, as suggested at the linked page.

As an aside, you can probably change `first = next(order)` to `first = next(reader)`. This way you'll have a list of strings (a row), and counting the occurrences of a certain string in it may be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

According to the python documentation of the csv module (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv), in order to translate that method in Python 3 you should use the next() function on your CSV reader object:

```
csvreader.__next__()

Return the next row of the reader’s iterable object as a list, parsed according to the current dialect. Usually you should call this as next(reader).
```

I hope that this will help you

Cheers

Comment: But the problem is not with the `next` method. Replacing it with the call to the `next()` function is the right thing to do and works on both versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in opening the file with mode='rb'. I found that if you open with mode 'r', then it should work:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as Order:
```

When openning with 'rb', Python3 interpret the file as a series of bytes and read the contents as such. With mod 'r', Python3 reads the file as strings.